# Hadoop scheduling map process to the file location

Tags: hadoop

I have a use case wherein i need to process huge set of files stored in HDFS. Those files are non-splittable and they need to be processed single map process. I wish to schedule the map process in task tracker where data is already available. How can I do it? Currently, I have a file that contains list of filenames. Each map get one line of it via NLineInputFormat. The map process then access the file via FSDataInputStream and work with it. Is there a way to ensure this map process is running on the node where the file is available?. I would like to avoid WholeFileINputFormat as I read it would load the values of the file and feed to the mapper.